# Converting a two dimensional int array to a byte array

Tags: c#, type-conversion, byte, arrays

I want to convert a two dimensional int array to a byte array. what is the most simple way to do so? 
 Example:

```
int[,] array = new int[2, 2] { { 2, 1 }, { 0, 1 } };
```

How can i convert `array` to a `byte[]`? On your answer, please include also the reverse function to that. (if there is a function to convert an `int[,]` to a `byte[]` please show me also how to convert a `byte[]` to an `int[,]` ) 
If you're asking yourself why do i need to do it: i need to send a `int[,]` over a TCP client to a server, then send a response to the client 

PS: I thought about making a `[Serializeable]` class, which will contain the `int[,]`, then serialize the class into a file and send that file, on the server side i will deserialize that file and get the array from there. but i thought that it would take a lot more resrouces to do that then just converting it to a `byte[]`. 
Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: `Buffer.BlockCopy`.

```
public static byte[] ToBytes<T>(this T[,] array) where T : struct
{
  var buffer = new byte[array.GetLength(0) * array.GetLength(1) * System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
  Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  return buffer;
}
public static void FromBytes<T>(this T[,] array, byte[] buffer) where T : struct
{
  var len = Math.Min(array.GetLength(0) * array.GetLength(1) * System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)), buffer.Length);
  Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, array, 0, len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't afraid of using unsafe code it's really simple:

```
        int[,] array = new int[2, 2];

        //Do whatever to fill the array

        byte[] buffer = new byte[array.GetLength(0) * array.GetLength(1) * sizeof(int)];

        fixed (void* pArray = &array[0,0])
        {
            byte* pData = (byte*)pArray;

            for (int buc = 0; buc < buffer.Length; buc++)
                buffer[buc] = *(pData + buc);

        }
```